# Running the Clean, Build and Rebuild through the Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I want to run the Clean, Build and Rebuild commands through the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio but so far I haven't been able to find how.

The following command gets me the first project inside the solution:

```
$project = Get-Project | select -First 1
```

When I run the `$project | Get-Member`, I can see the members of `$project` item.

```
#Members of the $project ($project | Get-Member)

#   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{866311e6-c887-4143-9833-645f5b93f6f1}
#
#Name                 MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                   
#----                 ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                   
#ProjectName          CodeProperty          System.String ProjectName{get=GetCustomUniqueName;}                                                                                          
#Delete               Method                void Delete ()                                                                                                                               
#Save                 Method                void Save (string)                                                                                                                           
#SaveAs               Method                void SaveAs (string)                                                                                                                         
#Extender             ParameterizedProperty IDispatch Extender (string) {get}                                                                                                            
#CodeModel            Property              CodeModel CodeModel () {get}                                                                                                                 
#Collection           Property              Projects Collection () {get}                                                                                                                 
#ConfigurationManager Property              ConfigurationManager ConfigurationManager () {get}                                                                                           
#DTE                  Property              DTE DTE () {get}                                                                                                                             
#ExtenderCATID        Property              string ExtenderCATID () {get}                                                                                                                
#ExtenderNames        Property              Variant ExtenderNames () {get}                                                                                                               
#FileName             Property              string FileName () {get}                                                                                                                     
#FullName             Property              string FullName () {get}                                                                                                                     
#Globals              Property              Globals Globals () {get}                                                                                                                     
#IsDirty              Property              bool IsDirty () {get} {set}                                                                                                                  
#Kind                 Property              string Kind () {get}                                                                                                                         
#Name                 Property              string Name () {get} {set}                                                                                                                   
#Object               Property              IDispatch Object () {get}                                                                                                                    
#ParentProjectItem    Property              ProjectItem ParentProjectItem () {get}                                                                                                       
#ProjectItems         Property              ProjectItems ProjectItems () {get}                                                                                                           
#Properties           Property              Properties Properties () {get}                                                                                                               
#Saved                Property              bool Saved () {get} {set}                                                                                                                    
#UniqueName           Property              string UniqueName () {get}                                                                                                                   
#Type                 ScriptProperty        System.Object Type {get=switch ($this.Kind) {...
```

I am not sure if I can get to the Clean Build and Rebuild method through the `$project` item or if I should I directly run the msbuild by targeting the project path.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the motivation for doing this from the Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visual Studio's object model provides a way to build the entire solution or a single project via the [SolutionBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.solutionbuild%28v=vs.100%29) object.

Building the solution is straightforward from the NuGet Package Manager Console.

```
$dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean($true)
$dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build($true)
```

The $true flag indicates that the command should wait for the clean/build to finish.

Building an individual project is not as straightforward. The SolutionBuild object provides a [BuildProject method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.solutionbuild.buildproject%28v=vs.100%29) which takes three parameters.

```
$project = Get-Project | select -First 1
$dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject("Debug", $project.FullName, $true)
```

It also does not allow you to run a Clean build.

If you want to build an individual project then, as Pavel suggests, using MSBuild seems to be more straighforward.

Comment: One of the best answers I have got in SO so far. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

According nuget [docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) there are no commands to do this actions. I think the simplest way to run msbuild directly.

```
$project = Get-Project | select -First 1
$msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
& $msbuild $project.FullName /t:Clean`;Build`;Rebuild
```

Based on this you can write your PS module and pack it like nuget package to share it with other developers and reuse in other projects. [Good example how to add PS commands by nuget](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/19/writing-a-nuget-package-that-adds-a-command-to-the.aspx).

Comment: NuGet docs doesn't show all the available actions that can be done.

Comment: I mean that nuget extension provides not to much additional commands, but you can execute all PS commands is this console. And it's common practice to call msbuild from PS by this way. Why don't you want write small PS module and pack it's as nuget package?

Comment: I will put that into my nuget profile. I don't want this as a nuget package. Also, you don't need special commands. PMC provides the very low level object: $dte. You can do or get to the many things from there. E.g: `($dte.Windows | Where { $_.Type -eq "vsWindowTypeSolutionExplorer" }).Object.SelectedItems.Object | select -First 1` gives the same result as `Get-Project | select -First 1` Here, I am looking for if there a native support or not for Clean, Build and Rebuild actions. I hope I am clear.